# Why does the following code, having sizeof keyword give me 0 and not 1?

Tags: c, sizeof, implicit-conversion

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d", -3 < sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

I hear the return type of `sizeof` is *size_t* and not *int*.
Can anyone tell me about this size_t or any other explanation?

Comment: To avoid the implicit conversion to `unsigned` you have to cast the result of `sizeof` back to `int`.